# Is blowing on a frying pan unsanitary?

Tags: food-safety

Does this look sanitary to you? I think if I wanted to put out a flame I'd use a pan lid.

[image]

Comment: I doubt he can *put out a flame* this way. It looks more like he wants to enlarge the burn by supplying extra air (oxygen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Incomplete common sense answer (no idea about local regulations. If this should have been a comment, somebody tell me! :) People breathe in kitchens while there are open pots, and blowing is a form of breathing. Food is not ever considered completely sterile unless pressure cooked/canned, cold sterilized (chemically or by pickling in extremely harsh pickling solutions), or irradiated. Also, unless things are served straight after that, they will be rather thoroughly cooked in the depicted scenario - if there are germs in that breath, they are cooked to death; spores will not matter much with food immediately served; if there was poison the cook would be dead or ill too. Virii could be a problem too,

Comment: It makes sense to me that in this scenario any germs transferred would be burned off. I guess to me it just looks wrong, I mean if you have seen videos of people sneezing or breathing and the light is right you can see all the droplets.